# HTML editor like Github issues in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, github, rich-text-editor

I want an editor just like GITHUB(Markdown) which provide custom buttons to alter just like in Github where I can write code as well as image and corresponding HTML should be previewed. I want use it in my React js project.

[GITHUB Editor](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new): like this editor or like Stackoverflow

[GITHUB Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fxbp.png)

Comment: Can I know why I my question downgraded

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's called "markdown editor". For `react` you can take a look at this [react-md-editor](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-md-editor/)